# How does cv2.imencode works? Output different shapes of two images of the same shape

Tags: python, opencv

I have two images with same shape and using `cv2.imencode` I got two array with different shapes, why this? How can I get encoded images of the same shape?

```
print(img1.shape)
OUTPUT: (720, 1280, 3)
print(img2.shape)
OUTPUT: (720, 1280, 3)

img1_encoded = cv2.imencode('.png', img1)
img2_encoded = cv2.imencode('.png', img2)

print(img1_encoded)
OUTPUT: (927851, 1)
print(img2_encoded)
OUTPUT: (73513, 1)
```

Comment: Is img1 identical to img2?

Comment: No they are different

Comment: png images are compressed. So for different input images, you may get different output byte size.

Answer (score 1):

The function imencode compresses an image and stores it in the memory buffer that is resized to fit the result.

img.shape returns the dimensions of the image and the number of channels in the image, in this case both your images have 3 channels indicating that they are colour images.

In laymen terms, image compression is dependant upon the frequency of a particular colour component within an image.

Given that you are encoding different images, they will always have a different output size.

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter09.html - Here is a link into how png compression works.